# How do I generate an assertion token for Sharepoint Access on behalf of another user in C#

Tags: c#, api, sharepoint

I have a web application with a number of modules. One of the modules grabs a number of excel files from SharePoint directories, and then combines the data in them. So far, I have been just mapping the folders to OneDrive and accessing them that way. But this always uses my OneDrive credentials, which need to be refreshed from time to time. The right way to do this is to access them directly from Sharepoint on behalf of the user logged into my web application. I have the delegated API permission things set up in Azure, and I have the client ID and secret, etc.. I've been reading a number of articles on how to do this. All of them talk about how to get the token on behalf of someone else. These articles also talk about the assertion token needing to be passed in order to get the on behalf of token. However, they don't tell you how to get the assertion token in the first place. Here is the code I currently have:

'''var client = new RestClient("https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXX/oauth2/v2.0/token");

```
        var request = new RestRequest();
        request.Method = Method.Post;
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.AddParameter("client_id", "MYCLIENTID", ParameterType.GetOrPost);
        request.AddParameter("client_secret", "MYSECRET", ParameterType.GetOrPost);
        request.AddParameter("scope", "https://MYTenent.sharepoint.com/.default", ParameterType.GetOrPost);
        request.AddParameter("grant_type", "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer", ParameterType.GetOrPost);
        request.AddParameter("requested_token_use", "on_behalf_of", ParameterType.GetOrPost);

        RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);'''
```

The result of this is of course an error that the assertion was not supplied. I didn't supply any more code, because I can't even get passed this. The rest of my code takes the token and passes it to an auth provider, which is then used to instantiate the GraphServiceClient. Based on what I've read, that client is then used to get the lists, files, etc...

So, my question is, how do I get the assertion token in the first place? I'm hoping the code I have written so far is in the correct direction and all I'm missing is the assertion token.

UPDATE:
I've gotten one answer that really didn't help. I pretty much copied and pasted the code (replacing the clientID, etc..) and I received an error> I was going to copy and paste it from the solution comments provided in the answer, but I guess you can't do that while editing.

Someone also asked if I was able to get the auth code from the URL. The answer to that is no. We use 2 factor authentication, and I tried to manually look at the URLS as I was logging in, while using break points to slow things down a bit. And I did not see an auth code. I did put a break point directly after the line of code:

```
var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
```

And when I look at the info variable, I can see 4 tokens. One of them is an access token and another is an ID token. The last one is an expiration date. I don't see an auth code, and from what I understand,  by the time I see the access code, it's too late. The auth code was already used to get the access code.

UPDATE 2:
I know that OBO is not what I want. I also know that in order to use delegated permissions, I need to use the Auth Code flow and not client credentials. I can't seem to get the auth code from the users initial log in. And I don't know how to get it otherwise.

For those of you that might be thinking "Does he need to be spoon fed?", the answer is yes, I do. I need a simple code example that will get me the auth code, so I can use it in the rest of the code I already have. If anyone can paste that code into an answer and not provide a link, that would be great. I'm sorry,  but the links I have been given, just go to microsoft learn sites that go through the explaination, but don't give any code samples.

Answer (score 1):

The OBO flow is obviously not applicable in your context, and if you're going to get an access token on behalf of a logged in user,  then you should focus on [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) or [ROPC flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc).

The corresponding C# code segment is:

```
using Microsoft.Graph; 
using Azure.Identity;


var scopes = new[] { "https://{tenant-name}.sharepoint.com/.default" };

// Multi-tenant apps can use "common",
// single-tenant apps must use the tenant ID from the Azure portal
var tenantId = "tenant id";

// Values from app registration
var clientId = "client id";
var clientSecret = "client secret";

// For authorization code flow, the user signs into the Microsoft
// identity platform, and the browser is redirected back to your app
// with an authorization code in the query parameters
var authorizationCode = "authorization code ";

// using Azure.Identity;
var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
};

// https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.identity.authorizationcodecredential
var authCodeCredential = new AuthorizationCodeCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, authorizationCode, options);


var accessToken = await authCodeCredential.GetTokenAsync(new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(scopes) { });

Console.WriteLine(accessToken.Token);
  
//var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authCodeCredential, scopes);
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why you say its obvious that OBO is not what I need here, can you please help me understand that? I mean, I am getting files in sharepoint on behalf of someone and I do want their credentials to be used. Sorry, just confused.

Comment: Also, I see that you are getting the auth code from the identity sign in, but our users sign into a multi-module app. Is there a way to retrieve the token after they are signed in, or does that need to be captured immediately?

Comment: Wait, Okay, I think I understand why OBO is not what I need. The person signing into the app is the one who will be accessing the files on sharepoint. So, I just need to be able to pass their credentials to sharepoint. That makes more sense.

Comment: I put a break point right after the user logs in, and I can see the code in the response. Is there a way to access that code later?

Comment: Yes, OBO flow is usually used for calls between 2 different types of apis, and you only need to call SharePoint REST APIs, so OBO flow does not apply to your context.

Comment: The user must log in interactively in a browser to obtain an authentication code, which is then redeemed for an access token. You can refer to the workflow of auth code flow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#protocol-details.

Comment: An authentication code can only be used once, and it expires after it is redeemed for an access token.

Comment: I pretty much copied and pasted the code above and got this error: Azure.Identity.AuthenticationFailedException: 'AuthorizationCodeCredential authentication failed: AADSTS9002313: Invalid request. Request is malformed or invalid.
Trace ID: 9aa0178b-07eb-4ac6-b256-bc6453db1800
Correlation ID: 90ba6aae-c04c-4667-8c2b-b4729ecc2fea
Timestamp: 2023-02-14 16:10:08Z'

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this does not work. All I want to do is access some files on Sharepoint using Microsoft Graph, and I can't find a complete and simple code example to use. Nothing is available for 2023. It's all from early 2022 and earlier. It's all outdated.

Comment: Have you obtained the authorization code in the browser?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-authorization-code ```https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=redirect_uri
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://{tenant-name}.sharepoint.com/.default
&state=12345```

Comment: Hi, I am checking to see if this issue is resolved or not. If you have any concerns, please feel free to reply.

Comment: Nope, it's not resolved. It looks like nobody can actually resolve this. I have another question, which shows more of the code I have.  Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75454351/i-just-want-to-access-some-files-from-my-net-core-web-application-using-microso/75459399?noredirect=1#comment133176452_75459399

Comment: I get the code you provided above, and I would like to use it. However, there is one big problem that I don't know how to solve. I will run that code in a utility class, so I can access Microsoft Graph. But, the user is already logged in by then. How to I get the Authorization code AFTER the user is logged in?